# How can I make an editable table with React-Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable, react-table

I've made this functional component in React, with React-Table module. 
Everything works fine, it loads a data-base into "Datos" object and it shows the data in their respective columns.

The thing is, HOW COULD I MAKE THIS TABLE EDITABLE? All the examples I see use State, which is not possible in my case because I'm not on App.js and I'm using functional components.
The code is as follows. If you need some additional information let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table.css'                

const Capturas = ({datos}) => { 

    const columns = [
        {
            id:'timeStamp',     
            Header: 'TIME STAMP',
            accessor: datos=>   timeFormat(datos.day) + '/'+ timeFormat(datos.month) + '/' + timeFormat(datos.year) + ' ' +   
                                timeFormat(datos.hour) + ':' + timeFormat(datos.minute) + ':' + timeFormat(datos.second),   
        },
        {
            id:'NAME',
            Header: 'NAME',
            accessor: datos=>datos.NAME,
        },
        {
            id:'SURNAME',
            Header: 'SURNAME',
            accessor:datos=>datos.SURNAME,
        },
        {
            id: 'location',
            Header: 'LOCATION',
            accessor: datos=>datos.location,
            width: 150,
        },
        {
            id: 'range',
            Header: 'RANGE (m)',
            accessor: datos=>datos.range,
            width: 150,
        },
    ]
    return( 
            <ReactTable 
            className = "center -striped -highlight bg-light"
            filterable={true}
            data = {datos}                      
            columns = {columns}                 
            />
    )
} 
export default Capturas;
```

}

Comment: You said that all the example shows using state, but you are not in App.js and you are using functional components. But you can still use state with [React Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), in functional components. If you can create codesandbox may be we can help you.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on why you can't use state? What @MSoheb has said is correct, React Hooks can indeed be implemented to grant state access within functional components. Alternatively, you can use props passed down from a parent component.

Comment: The example I've seen is this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-editable-content-nq928
How could I migrate this example to Hooks? I'm very new in React, so I don't understand deeply the Hooks yet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create your own codesandbox?